# how to query DBF(dbase) files date type field in where and between clause

Tags: c#, sql, dbf, dbase

I have a DBF file and I'm trying  read it from c# code. I can read files successfully without applying any conditions or applying conditions for varchar type fields.My problem is I have to filter the records from the Date field (type:date). I have tried following ways,

```
SELECT * FROM D:\DBFreader\file.dbf where [RDATE] between 2/16/2006 12:00:00 AM and 2/20/2006 12:00:00 AM
```

above gives a syntax Error: missing operator

```
SELECT * FROM D:\DBFreader\file.dbf where [RDATE] between '2/16/2006 12:00:00 AM' and '2/20/2006 12:00:00 AM'
```

above gives a data type mismatch error

```
SELECT * FROM D:\DBFreader\file.dbf where [RDATE] between 2/16/2006 and 2/20/2006
```

above does not throw any exception, but does not return any records though there are matching records.

The same things happens for the where clause as well.
What can I do to filter records from a range

I'm using following code to read it

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connstring))
{
   connection.Open();
   cmd = new OdbcCommand(@"SELECT * FROM D:\DBFreader\file.dbf where [RDATE] between 2/16/2006 12:00:00 AM and 2/20/2006 12:00:00 AM", connection);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   da.SelectCommand = cmd;
   da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: Q: What's a ".dbf" file?  What program did you use to create them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK -

I believe the problem is that dBase/xBase doesn't support "between" for SQL dates

WORKAROUND:

`@"SELECT * FROM D:\DBFreader\file.dbf where [RDATE] >= #2/16/2006 12:00:00 AM# and [RDATE] < #2/20/2006 12:00:00 AM#"`

PS:
I know dBase syntax supports "date" literals (e.g. "2/16/2006"; I don't know about "datetime" - plese try it and see.

Comment: actually it supports between, the problem was i haven't used the # sign to surround date time value. Now it works fine. Thanks --SELECT * FROM D:\DBFreader\file.dbf where [RDATE] between #2/16/2006 12:00:00 AM# and #2/20/2006 12:00:00 AM#

Answer (score 4):

dbase/Foxpro syntax for BETWEEN (and works on any of same data types) is

```
BETWEEN( SomeValue, MinRange, MaxRange )
```

so your query could be done like

```
where between( [RDATE], ctod( '02/16/2006' ), ctod( '02/20/2006' ))
```

in old DBase and VFP forward, CTOD() stands for Character To Date conversion and expects in format like mm/dd/yyyy.  By doing just the "date" portion, it always implies 12:00:00 AM.

in addition, you could use the DATE() function available such as
date( yyyy, mm, dd ) as   Date( 2006, 02, 16 ) which would also return this specific date.

If you wanted a specific time, you could use CTOT() which represents Character TO dateTime field, such as

```
CTOT( "2012-09-20T15:16:21" )  = Sep 20, 2012 @ 3:16:21pm
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
WHERE RDATE >= {^2016-11-01} AND RDATE <= {^2017-01-31}
```

I checked this with **OLEDB Connection**