# DBF dBase - Where clause date Operator/operand type mismatch error

Tags: c#, date, dbf

trying to do a query on a dbf dBase which includes a where clause to only select the rows where a date is after 01/01/2018

I have tried all options in this thread but to no avail.
[how to query DBF(dbase) files date type field in where and between clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506295/how-to-query-dbfdbase-files-date-type-field-in-where-and-between-clause)

```
command.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM PAYHIST WHERE EMPLOYEE = '{0}' 
                                            AND PAY_DATE >= '#1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM#'", employee.WorksNumber);
```

This throws an " Operator/operand type mismatch." exception as does

```
between( [PAY_DATE], CTOT( "01-Jan-18 12:00:00 AM" ), CTOT( "31-Dec-18 12:00:00 AM" ))
```

and

```
between( [PAY_DATE], CTOT( '01 - Jan - 18 12:00:00 AM' ), CTOT( '31 - Dec - 18 12:00:00 AM' ))
```

while

```
AND PAY_DATE >= {^2018-01-01}
```

and

```
PAY_DATE >= {D ‘2018-01-01’}
```

throws an input string error.

Im running it on VS2015

any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `command.CommandText`?

Comment: Probably if you use # to delimit dates then you shouldn't use also single quotes

Comment: @steve when i take out the single quote the error is "Missing operand"

Comment: Looks like you mean [dbase timestamp](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/server1/dbf_field_types_and_specifications.htm)  because dbase `date` does not support time.

Comment: @bradbury9 when i try "PAY_DATE >= '#1/1/2018#'" it still throws the Operator/operand type mismatch error

Comment: between syntax is wrong. Between is not a function. Either you declare a string with `'` or a date with `#`. Both delimiters look wrong. Disclaimer, very long time since i last did dbase

Comment: @bradbury9 not for dbase/Foxpro syntax the link in my question points to an answer that uses Between in the syntax.

Comment: Between is not a function, but an operator, google it and you can get how to use it https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: @KenWhite first in the users questions and then in the second answer." where between( [RDATE], ctod( '02/16/2006' ), ctod( '02/20/2006' ))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when querying, you need to parameterize your queries, not embed them as strings.  The OleDB command execution process will handle the data type for you.  However note, parameters with OleDb against a .DBF based file use "?" as a place-holder for the parameters and need to be added to the command for each parameter needed...

```
command.CommandText = string.Format(
@"SELECT 
        PH.* 
    FROM 
        PAYHIST PH
    WHERE 
            PH.EMPLOYEE = ?
        AND PH.PAY_DATE >= ? ";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForEmployeeID", employee.WorksNumber );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForDateField", new date(2018,1,1) );
```

if doing between, you just have extra "?" place-holder

```
... WHERE 
            PH.EMPLOYEE = ?
        AND PH.PAY_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ? ";


    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForEmployeeID", employee.WorksNumber );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmFromDate", new date(2018,1,1) );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmToDate", new date(2018,12,31) );
```

There are PLENTY of examples on parameterizing queries... especially doing web-based to prevent SQL-Injection. -- and read-up on that too.

Comment: this still give the Operator/operand type mismatch error im afraid.

Comment: @CM99, confirm data types from each parameter.  Ex: if the employee ID is a numeric/integer, then don't pass in a string, you need an integer parameter.  if a field is just a date, make sure to pass in just date, not date/time.  Confirm and you may need to explicitly need to create a parameter object by explicitly designating the data type.  Read up on other samples with Command.Parameters.Add().